# Retrieving example for jshs2

Tags: node.js, hive

I have a working code to fire query on hive using node module "**jdbc**", as an alternative i was trying "**jshs**2" , i am able to connect to hive and fire query but still stuck to retrieve the resultset, can anyone who have used the "**jshs2**", module can put up an example.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just started a project where I have to connect to hive from node too. I was able to run a query on database and iterate through the resultset using the following demo code:

```js
const {
  Configuration,
  HiveConnection,
  IDLContainer,
} = require('jshs2');

const options = {
  auth: 'NOSASL',
  host: 'myServer',
  port: myPort,
};

const hiveConfig = new Configuration(options);
const idl = new IDLContainer();

async function main() {
  await idl.initialize(hiveConfig);
  const connection = await new HiveConnection(hiveConfig, idl);
  const cursor = await connection.connect();
  const res = await cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 10');

  if (res.hasResultSet) {
    const fetchResult = await cursor.fetchBlock();
    fetchResult.rows.forEach((row) => {
      console.log(row);
    });
  }

  cursor.close();
  connection.close();
}

main().then(() => {
  console.log('Finished.');
});
```

I'm using node v8.x, so I can use ES6 features like destructuring and async/await. If your node version is older you must work with promise chains.