# Expected state FINISHED but found RUNNING Error using await/sync with jshs2 for Hive 1.1.0

Tags: node.js, hive

I know this **jshs2** is out of date but it works for my use case. I did the test `npm run test:msg` and it works fine:

```
{
    "auth": "NOSASL",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 10000,
    "timeout": 10000,
    "username": "hive",
    "password": "hive",
    "hiveType": 1,
    "hiveVer": "0.13.1",
    "cdhVer": "5.3.0",
    "thriftVer": "0.9.2",
    "maxRows": 5120,
    "nullStr": "NULL",
    "i64ToString": true
  }
```

But I had a hard time to get the more modern way using await/async to work: [Retrieving example for jshs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375410/retrieving-example-for-jshs2)

My code:

```
const {
  Configuration,
  HiveConnection,
  IDLContainer,
} = require('jshs2');

const options = {
    "auth": "NOSASL",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 10000,
    "timeout": 10000,
    "username": "hive",
    "password": "hive",
    "hiveType": 1,
    "hiveVer": "0.13.1",
    "cdhVer": "5.3.0",
    "thriftVer": "0.9.2",
    "maxRows": 5120,
    "nullStr": "NULL",
    "i64ToString": true
};

const hiveConfig = new Configuration(options);
const idl = new IDLContainer();

console.log(options);

async function main() {
  console.log('main');
  await idl.initialize(hiveConfig);
  const connection = await new HiveConnection(hiveConfig, idl);
  const cursor = await connection.connect();
  // const res = await cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 10');
  const res = await cursor.execute('show databases');
  // console.log(res);

  if (res.hasResultSet) {
    const fetchResult = await cursor.fetchBlock();
    fetchResult.rows.forEach((row) => {
      console.log(row);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Error: res...');
    console.log(res);
  }

  cursor.close();
  connection.close();

  console.log('close');
}

main().then(() => {
  console.log('Finished.');
});
```

I got below error:

```
[root@demo testjshs2]# node test1.js
{ auth: 'NOSASL',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 10000,
  hiveType: 1,
  hiveVer: '0.13.1',
  cdhVer: '5.3.0',
  thriftVer: '0.9.2' }
main
(node:50708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Expected state FINISHED, but found RUNNING

-- Error caused from HiveServer2



*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Expected state FINISHED, but found RUNNING:27:26
org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:assertState:Operation.java:199
org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:getNextRowSet:SQLOperation.java:445
org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager:getOperationNextRowSet:OperationManager.java:294
org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:fetchResults:HiveSessionImpl.java:769
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl:invoke0:NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43
java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:606
org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:78
org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:access$000:HiveSessionProxy.java:36
org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1:run:HiveSessionProxy.java:63
java.security.AccessController:doPrivileged:AccessController.java:-2
javax.security.auth.Subject:doAs:Subject.java:415
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:doAs:UserGroupInformation.java:1917
org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:59
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26:fetchResults::-1
org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:fetchResults:CLIService.java:462
org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:FetchResults:ThriftCLIService.java:694
org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1553
org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1538
org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39
org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39
org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56
org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:286
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615
java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745
    at Client.FetchResults (/root/testjshs2/node_modules/jshs2/lib/HiveCursor.js:270:18)
    at client._reqs.(anonymous function) (/root/testjshs2/node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/connection.js:151:13)
    at exports.Client.TCLIServiceClient.recv_FetchResults (/root/testjshs2/node_modules/jshs2/idl/Thrift_0.9.2_Hive_0.13.1_CDH_5.3.0/TCLIService.js:2934:12)
    at /root/testjshs2/node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/connection.js:157:41
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/testjshs2/node_modules/thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/buffered_transport.js:48:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
(node:50708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:50708) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
^C
```

This is my Hiveserver2 log:

```
2018-04-10 16:29:30,648 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-52]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(703)) - Created local directory: /tmp/e8fe98e5-39ac-438b-8a33-36cf0da898dd_resources
2018-04-10 16:29:30,653 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-52]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(703)) - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/anonymous/e8fe98e5-39ac-438b-8a33-36cf0da898dd
2018-04-10 16:29:30,656 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-52]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(703)) - Created local directory: /tmp/hive/e8fe98e5-39ac-438b-8a33-36cf0da898dd
2018-04-10 16:29:30,666 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-52]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(703)) - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/anonymous/e8fe98e5-39ac-438b-8a33-36cf0da898dd/_tmp_space.db
2018-04-10 16:29:30,666 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-52]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:start(587)) - No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
2018-04-10 16:29:30,674 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-52]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:compile(497)) - Compiling command(queryId=hive_20180410162929_d52c8fad-b5ef-4797-a168-5be155876c09): show databases
2018-04-10 16:29:30,741 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-52]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:compile(570)) - Semantic Analysis Completed
2018-04-10 16:29:30,742 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-52]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:getSchema(303)) - Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:database_name, type:string, comment:from deserializer)], properties:null)
2018-04-10 16:29:30,743 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-52]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:compile(690)) - Completed compiling command(queryId=hive_20180410162929_d52c8fad-b5ef-4797-a168-5be155876c09); Time taken: 0.069 seconds
2018-04-10 16:29:30,746 WARN  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-52]: security.UserGroupInformation (UserGroupInformation.java:doAs(1920)) - PriviledgedActionException as:anonymous (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Expected state FINISHED, but found RUNNING
2018-04-10 16:29:30,746 WARN  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-52]: thrift.ThriftCLIService (ThriftCLIService.java:FetchResults(703)) - Error fetching results:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Expected state FINISHED, but found RUNNING
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.assertState(Operation.java:199)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.getNextRowSet(SQLOperation.java:445)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager.getOperationNextRowSet(OperationManager.java:294)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.fetchResults(HiveSessionImpl.java:769)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.fetchResults(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.fetchResults(CLIService.java:462)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.FetchResults(ThriftCLIService.java:694)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1553)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1538)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-04-10 16:29:30,749 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-63]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:checkConcurrency(223)) - Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
2018-04-10 16:29:30,749 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-63]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:execute(1656)) - Executing command(queryId=hive_20180410162929_d52c8fad-b5ef-4797-a168-5be155876c09): show databases
2018-04-10 16:29:30,750 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-63]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:launchTask(2050)) - Starting task [Stage-0:DDL] in serial mode
2018-04-10 16:29:30,762 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-63]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:execute(1958)) - Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20180410162929_d52c8fad-b5ef-4797-a168-5be155876c09); Time taken: 0.013 seconds
2018-04-10 16:29:30,762 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-63]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(1087)) - OK
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE 1**:

Turn out this thing run too fast:

`const res = await cursor.execute('show databases');`

will cause error at `if (res.hasResultSet)`

If I put in something in between such as `for (i=0;i<100000;i++) {console.log();}` to delay a bit, it works fine.

But I thought async/await supposes to handle these kinda thing???

Comment: It looks like jshs2 is an abandon project so it probably was not designed correctly to handle await/async

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var jshs2 = require('jshs2');
var HS2Util = jshs2.HS2Util;

await idl.initialize(hiveConfig);
const connection = await new HiveConnection(hiveConfig, idl);
let serviceType = idl.ServiceType;
let cursor = await connection.connect();
const ress = await cursor.execute(queryString);
for (let i = 0, len = 1000; i < len; i += 1) {
     const status = await cursor.getOperationStatus();
     const log = await cursor.getLog();
     console.log('Status: ' + HS2Util.getState(serviceType, status));

     console.log('Log: ' + log);

     if (HS2Util.isFinish(cursor, status)) {
         break;
     }

     await HS2Util.sleep(5000);                                           }
```